start-process : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command
I am adding the Powershell task in the Azure pipeline to start the exe by taking the commands in the pipe and starting the process with two argument lists. Also I have to wait for the exe to load with the argument then pass the command(s). Can we do that without start-process
Here is my script
$exeArguments = "arg1", "arg2"
"command1" | start-process -FilePath myapplication.exe -ArgumentList $exeArguments 

And I am getting the following error

start-process : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not
take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (init-instrument:String) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand



Does the start-process do not take pipe input and arguments at the same time?

Read Start-Process docs. There is no parameter accepting pipeline input…

Why use start-process at all if you're not waiting?


No, Start-Process fundamentally does not accept pipeline input, as JosefZ notes.
Instead, you must use the -RedirectStandardInput parameter, to which you must pass the path of a (possibly temporary) file containing the data you want to send to the target process' stdin (standard input) stream.

Here's a simple (contrived example):
# Create a temporary file...
$tempFile = New-TemporaryFile
# ... and fill it with sample data.
@'
hi
there
'@ | Set-Content $tempFile

# "Pipe" the file's content to `findstr.exe hi`, i.e. send it
# to the latter's stdin stream.
# This will print 'hi', i.e. the matching line to the console.
Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardInput $tempFile -FilePath findstr.exe -ArgumentList hi 

# Clean up.
$tempFile | Remove-Item

Note that, similarly, you cannot directly capture output from a Start-Process-launched process in PowerShell's pipeline, and must use -RedirectStandardOutput and -RedirectStandardError to send the output to files.
(In the sample command above, -NoNewWindow ensures that the process' output prints to the console, however, it cannot be captured.)

Taking a step back:

If myapplication.exe is a console (terminal-based) application, and your intent is to execute it synchronously in the current console (terminal), there is no need to use Start-Process - just call it directly, in which case you can provide stdin input directly via the pipeline:[1]
$exeArguments = "arg1", "arg2"
"command1" | myapplication.exe @exeArguments 


This also allows you to directly capture its output and query the process exit code via the automatic $LASTEXITCODE variable.


See this answer for details and this guidance for when use of Start-Process is and isn't appropriate.



[1] Note that it is the value of the $OutputEncoding preference variable that controls the character encoding PowerShell uses for the data being sent to an external application (invariably as text up to PowerShell 7.3.x; in 7.4+, sending arbitrary [byte]s is now supported). Complementarily, it is the value of [Console]::OutputEncoding that determines how PowerShell decodes data received from an external application's stdout and stderr streams.
See this answer for more information.

Thank you for this answer it helped. I did not need the start-process. As suggested I just called the exe directly.
But here I am wanting to wait for the exe to load and then run the commands. Can I do that without start-process ?

You have provided two solutions above. The one I tried is using Pipe (I) input to the exe was giving the error.
However I replaced that with your first solution using Start-process and provide the commands through the file. That worked amazingly. Thanks a lot.
you are the hero :)
I am going to post your solution as the answer to my other question
